# Calculating the complexity of an algorithm with 3 loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I tried to solve the following exercise :

What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment
as a function of N?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j*j; k++)
            sum++;
```

and I found that the complexity is O(n<sup>4</sup>), however the correct answer is  :

> The answer is : N<sup>7</sup>
>
> For a given value of i, the body of the innermost loop is executed 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> ~ 1/3 i<sup>6</sup> times. Summing up over all values of i yields ~ 1/21 N<sup>7</sup>.

I would like some help to understand this answer and the correct way to calculate complexity in this case.

EDIT : In particular, I don't understand this statement :

1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> ~ 1/3 i<sup>6</sup>

Because for me, <sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> ~ i<sup>4</sup>

Comment: take a look here and you will understand more better http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms

Comment: That's a very general article for a very specific question.

Comment: I've added some more info to address your edit.

Comment: @otus Seems like you have a good student book, can you share with me the name ?

Comment: @rahpuser Actually this is from "Algorithms, part 1" course on coursera (By robert sedgewick, Princeton) and the course is based on the book "algorithms 4th edition" by robert sedgewick

Comment: [link for the course](https://fr.coursera.org/course/algs4partI)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT:

I'll add a bit of explanation to clear up your confusion about the quote in your question. Let's consider a fixed value of `i` and focus on the innermost two loops:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j*j; k++)
        sum++;
```

How many times is the j-loop iterated? The answer is i^2 times. On each of *those* iterations, the k-loop is iterated j^2 times, which is different for each outer iteration because the value of j increases from 1 all the way to i^2.

When j = 1, the k-loop iterates 1^2 times. When j = 2, the k-loop iterates 2^2 times. When j=3, 3^2 times. Tallying up the total number of the iterations of the k-loop over all values of j, you have 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + (i^2)^2, since j runs between 1 and i^2. Hopefully that clarifies how you arrive at the following statement:

> For a given value of i, the body of the innermost loop is executed 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> ~ 1/3 i<sup>6</sup> times.

---

The total number of iterations can be expressed in sum form. The innermost loop has exactly `j^2` iterations for each (varying) value of j, the middle loop has `i^2` iterations for each value of i, and the outermost loop has `N` iterations. More neatly, the exact number of iterations is:

[image]

Multiplying through, you'll find this is a 7th order polynomial in N, so it is apparent why this is O(N^7).

In case you doubt the answer above is correct, simply run your own code and compare the value of `sum` you get with the formula provided above:

```
var sum = 0;
var N = 10;

for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for (var j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
        for (var k = 1; k <= j*j; k++)
            sum++;

function T(N) { return (1/420)*N*(1+N)*(1+2*N)*(8+11*N+21*N*N+20*N*N*N+10*N*N*N*N); }

console.log(sum===T(N));
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wby9deax/. No matter what value of N you put in the answer will be correct (note: be careful with large values for N, it will probably freeze up your browser, since the number of iterations grows very rapidly).

Comment: Could whoever downvoted please explain what I got wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't there 3  sums in your calculus since there is three nested loops ?

Comment: @otusThe innermost loop is sum from k=1 to j^2 of 1, which is just j^2.

Answer (score 4):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)            -- O(N^1)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)      -- O(N^2)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j*j; k++)  -- O(N^4)
            sum++;
```

Since they're nested (and since they're all linear) you get O(N<sup>1</sup> × N<sup>2</sup> × N<sup>4</sup>) = O(N<sup>1+2+4</sup>) = O(N<sup>7</sup>)

---

> EDIT : In particular, I don't understand this statement :
>
> 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + (i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> ~ 1/3 i<sup>6</sup>

Keep in mind that you may have *N* terms hiding in the "…" part.

Comment: You' don't actually have N^7 iterations. It is O(N^7), but certainly not N^7.

Comment: Why is the last loop O(n^4) and not O(n^2) since it has the same structure as the second loop ?

Comment: Ah, good question. This is because it runs over `1...j*j` (and not `1...i*i`). `j` is `O(n^2)` so `j*j` is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: While this is correct here, there is a major pitall with the "Let's multiply big Os to get the answer" approach, specifically when the loops are logarithimic behavior: `for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) ...` This will NOT be `Theta(nlogn)`.

Comment: Woops, made a typo - supposed to be: `for(int i = 1; i < n; i*=2) for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) ...`. This is NOT `Theta(nlogn)`, and the "let's multuply big Os" approach fails here. it works in this case though.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a different story. This question is plain linear behavior in all loops, though. But sure, I agree that it's a simplification which is not always valid. Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: @otus, did you understand my explanation for the `O(n^4)` part?

Comment: @aioobe By the way, is there a mathematical property or proof that you are using when you say "Since they're nested (and since they're all linear)" ?

Answer (score 2):

because will be 
N^1 loops - first for
N^2 loops - second for
N^4 loops - third for 
and N^1 * N^2 * N^4 = N^7

Answer (score 2):

I think it is good idea to substitute variables (i,j and k) by N values.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) //<- i = N
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++) //<- i*i = N*N
        for (int k = 1; k <= j*j; k++) //<- j*j = (i*i)*(i*i) =  N*N*N*N
```

In the first loop number of iterations will be N, that's simple part.
In second loop number of iterations will be `N*N`. In the third - `N*N*N*N`.

So finally, number of iterations will be N (first loop), times `N*N` (second), times `N*N*N*N` (third), so `N*(N*N)*(N*N*N*N)` = `N^7`