# What is the time complexity in this case?

Tags: time-complexity

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
    function();
    //do something
  }
}

function() {
  for(int i = 0; i < k; k++) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

So there is a loop inside another for loop and then in the inner loop, there is a function call which again runs in linear time complexity. In this case, am I looking at the time complexity of O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a time complexity of `O(n^2*k)`. Because, once you are in the second loop, for  each `j`, you have to do `function()`, which is another loop, then for each `j` you are making another `for loop` of complexity `O(k)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {             -----O(n)
      for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {     -----O(n)
        function();                      -----O(k)
        //do something
      }
    }
```

Because

```
function() {
  for(int i = 0; i < k; k++) {       -----O(k)
    //do something
  }
}
```

Since they're nested and since they're all linear you get O(n × n × k) = O(n^2*k). Thanks to [Jacob Steinebronn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13674351/jacob-steinebronn) for the specification.
Checkout this links [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007336/calculating-the-complexity-of-an-algorithm-with-3-loops) for more info.

Comment: Close. It's actually `O(n^2*k)` since k is not defined with relationship to n

Comment: Here k will run for n/2 times. So this means, we can say it is O(n^3). Thank you for your answer.